# VS 2013 not finding a string

Tags: search, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express. I am using ctrl/shift/f to search for a string. It is not finding the string. Here is the result of the search:

```
Find all "tsolb", Keep modified files open, Find Results 1, "C:\DokanTestDirectory\2220", "*.s"
  No files were found to look in.
```

But if I use a CMD method the string is found:

```
C:\>findstr /s /i "tsolb" "C:\DokanTestDirectory\2220\*.s"
C:\DokanTestDirectory\2220\TSO.S:*MACLIB TSOLB

C:\>
```

To try to isolate the problem I copied TSO.S to another directory and tried VS again ... That works:

```
Find all "tsolb", Keep modified files open, Find Results 1, "c:\temp\2220", "*.s"
  C:\temp\2220\TSO.S(1):*MACLIB TSOLB                                                                   
  Matching lines: 1    Matching files: 1    Total files searched: 1
```

Here is the content of both directories:

```
C:\>dir c:\DokanTestDirectory\2220 /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ECBC-051A

 Directory of c:\DokanTestDirectory\2220

12/02/2014  07:55 PM    <DIR>          .
12/02/2014  07:55 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/28/2014  06:06 PM           951,692 TSO.S
               1 File(s)        951,692 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  166,707,027,968 bytes free

C:\>dir c:\temp\2220 /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is ECBC-051A

 Directory of c:\temp\2220

12/02/2014  07:57 PM    <DIR>          .
12/02/2014  07:57 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/28/2014  06:06 PM           951,692 TSO.S
               1 File(s)        951,692 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  166,707,548,160 bytes free

C:\>
```

Does anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The folder c:\DokanTestDirectory\2220 had the S attribute but when I made the folder c:\temp\2220, the folder 2220 did not get the S attribute. So I guess VS 2013 Express will not find files within a folder which has the S attribute unless you specifically name the file.